# How to work with associations in Visual Studio's class diagram?

Tags: c#, visual-studio, visual-studio-2017, uml, class-diagram

I'm setting my first steps in Visual Studio's class diagrams for a C# project.

In the class diagram, I have already managed to create a new class, add fields, properties and methods, make an association from a single class to another single class, and automatically generate the corresponding code. I have also already generated a class diagram from an existing C# project.

Two things I've not succeeded in, and which are quite crucial:

- I create two classes in the class diagram, I create an association, I generate the source code and I remove the class diagram from the project. I re-create the class diagram from the autogenerated source code, but I don't see any association.
- I create two classes in the class diagram, and I would like to create a one-to-many association. I have no idea how to do this.

I'm working with Visual Studio 2017, enterprise edition, version 15.9.36.

Does anybody know what I can do? (Are those known bugs, am I doing something wrong and what should I do instead, am I using a wrong version of Visual Studio for this, ...?)

Thanks in advance

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I reproduced the first problem. You could try to right-click the class diagram and select **Show as Association**(one to one) or **Show as Collection Association**(one to many) to show the connections between the class diagrams.

[image]

For one-to-many relationships, you can use list. Here is a simple example:

```
class Person
  {
    public string Name { get; set; }
    public int Age { get; set; }
    public List<Family> Fmailies { get; set; }
   //Code automatically generated when the class diagram creates an Association
    internal Family Family
    {
      get => default;
      set
      {
      }
    }
  }

class Family
  {
    public string Name { get; set; }
    public string Relation { get; set; }
    
  }
```

Corresponding class diagram:

[image]

**Edit：**
It is normal to create new classes when using classes that are not in the class diagram. Association is based on existing attributes. You could create attributes first, and then establish associations.

I think the association between the classes may be detectable, but it is not explicitly shown in the class diagram.

Currently, I have not found a way to automatically display the association in visual studio. You could display the association manually.

Comment: I tried this, and is does exactly as you say, but, in case a "class" is used which is not in the class diagram, it gets added as an extra class, even basic types as `int32`. I was hoping for a feature, who could detect the associations between classes in the class diagram, and automatically show all of them, but I understand this might not be implemented yet?

Comment: ＠Dominique. I have updated my answer, you could check it．